# What is Facebook permanent user Access Token data access validity

Tags: facebook, token

I have get Facebook permanent access token. And check it in access token debugger. Here i can see that it shows "Expires :Never "  and "Data Access Expires : 156*632** (in about 3 months)" . Here expire(never) is OK, but what does it mean by Data Access Expires (in about 3 months). Does it means data access fro 3 months or anything else. If yes then what's the meaning of Expires (Never).

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/auth-vs-data

Comment: there is no permanent user access token...